# Solve multivariate symbolic equation (equation for hyperplane) in MATLAB and then sym2poly?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, symbolic-math

So I'm working on a 5-d problem whereby I'm trying to solve for an equation of a hyperplane in this space. I've attempted to do this via the following:

```
 syms g g1 g2 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
 g_1=-log(det(sig1_new)^(1/2))-(1/2)*([x1;x2;x3;x4;x5]-u1')'*inv(sig1_new)*   ([x1;x2;x3;x4;x5]-u1')+log(p1);
 g_2=-log(det(sig2_new)^(1/2))-(1/2)*([x1;x2;x3;x4;x5]-u2')'*inv(sig2_new)*     ([x1;x2;x3;x4;x5]-u2')+log(p2);
 g=g_1-g_2
 plane=solve(g_1-g_2,x5)
```

This does solve the system, but I'm not sure how to do anything relevant with the result because I cannot convert back into a polynomial, as there is more than one symbolic variable. I'm not sure, maybe I'm approaching my issue wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear what you want, but you can use `matlabFunction` to convert `plane` into an anonymous function with 4 inputs, `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`:

```
planeFunc=matlabFunction(plane)
```

Comment: Well I've never solved for these types of planes, so I assumed just solving for one of the dimensional variables would do the trick. I have never heard of matlabFunction and will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Solving for one variable gives you an equation for that variable in terms of the other 4. If the matrices/vectors `sig1_new`, `u1, etc. are just constant matrices, you will have a linear function of the variables `x1`,...,`x5`. But it's hard to tell just looking at your code what those matrices are and what you wish to do with the results.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't specify much. sig1_new, u1 are all constants. I'm working to implement a perceptron criterion of a linear discriminant function. So, first I'm trying to get what I consider a "seed" hyper plane and then move the plane according to certain conditions